# print value shown as none

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm wondering why the variable `lengthOfList` can store `len(l)` but the variable `reverseOfList` cannot store a method being called on a list. 
If I call `l.reverse()` and `print(l)` I can see the reverse but why can't the reversed list be stored in a variable?

Please see example code below.

```
    l = [1,2,3]

    lengthOfList = len(l) #3

    reverseOfList = l.reverse() # Global frame None

    print(reverseOfList) #None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.reverse()
>     Reverse the elements of the list in place.

This means the list is reversed in place, and the function returns `None`

You should try

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l.reverse()
>>> print(l)
[3, 2, 1]
```